# Как узнать, есть ли невалидные поля в WPF Окне

Tags: wpf, валидация

Имеется Окно (Window) WPF с огромной кучей полей и системой их валидации на основе IDataErrorInfo. Задача состоит в том, чтобы позволять пользователю сохранять данные окна и делать ему DialogResult = true даже с невалидными полями, но если есть хотя бы одно невалидное поле, то помечать соответствующий признак.

Подскажите, как легко в обработчике нажатия кнопки "OK" (закрывает окно) проверить наличие невалидных полей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, из-за того, что IDataErrorInfo обрабатывает только одну ошибку за раз, придется делать такой вот конструкт во VM:

```
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = String.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "RelationOther":
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RelationOther) && !RelationTypeMap[10])
                        error = "Ошибка! Указание описания не требуется"; break;
                case "ChildsNum":
                    if ((SexMap[0] || FullOld < 15) && (ChildsNum ?? 0) > 0)
                        error = "Ошибка! Количество детей указывают только женщины от 15 лет и старше"; break;
                case "ChildBirthDate":
                    if ((SexMap[0] || FullOld < 15) && ChildBirthDate != null)
                        error = "Ошибка! Дату рождения первого ребенка указывают только женщины от 15 лет и старше"; break;
            }
            return error;
        }
    }
    public string Error => string.Empty;

    public bool IsValid => Errors.Any(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e));

    public List<string> Errors => new List<string>()
    {
        this["RelationOther"],
        this["ChildsNum"],
        this["ChildBirthDate"]
    };
    #endregion
```

Тогда свойство isValid будет указывать на то, есть в окне на данный момент ошибки валидации.

Кто-нибудь знает лучшее решение?